# Is there any way I can use @mui/material in Angular?

Tags: angular, material-ui

I wanted to use `npm install @mui/material` but in Angular. Not sure if this is going to work. I am new to Angular too. If we can't use mui in Angular, is there any specific angular library to use that provides Material UI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yea you can't use React dedicated library in an Angular project, their just not compatible. However Angular does have Material design based library: https://material.angular.io/

Follow getting started instructions to add it to your project: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Then pick a component you would like to add. Follow the API docs to make the right imports. Paste an example in your project to get you started. https://material.angular.io/components/input/api

Comment: Hey. Thanks for helping me. I did find it but I'm still stuck at implementing it.

Comment: Any specific error messages your getting? What's the problem?

Comment: I have added a new question. You can find details there. Thanks a lot for helping.